# Jenkins throws NullPointerException after upgrading Splunk plugin

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception, jenkins-plugins

I got tired of the security prompt at the top of the Jenkins window telling me to upgrade my plugins, so I upgraded those plugins. When I rebooted, the familiar Jenkins landing page was replaced with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.utils.SplunkLogService.enqueue(SplunkLogService.java:174)
    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.utils.SplunkLogService.send(SplunkLogService.java:170)
    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.utils.SplunkLogService.send(SplunkLogService.java:107)
    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.JdkSplunkLogHandler.publish(JdkSplunkLogHandler.java:43)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:664)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.info(Logger.java:1182)
    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.LoggingInitStep.setupSplunkJenkins(LoggingInitStep.java:22)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1089)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:47)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1113)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:929)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:231)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:248)
```

Is there any way to recover from this aside from restoring a backup? I don't presently have shell access to the system, so please keep that in mind for your answers.

Jenkins version: 2.46.2

Splunk plugin version: 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get SSH access to the system and did the following to solve my problem. Solution taken from the [Removing and Disabling Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Removing+and+disabling+plugins) wiki page.

```
touch /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/splunk-devops.jpi.disabled
touch /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/splunk-devops-extend.jpi.disabled
```

Then, I rebooted. From the documentation, I assume that this is possible with any plugin.